# bullet doesn't bounce in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

In the "def Update" section.

According to the place where the four blocks,which are tagged, are placed. The bullet just goes past the screen or stays inside the screen blinking (because it changes its x,y to -x,-y all the time)

Bullet doesn't bounce unlike in other programs I've made. I think the problem is in the position of those four blocks. Can you tell me where to fix?

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,centerx,centery,c):
        ...

    def update(self):
        a= pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.b.append(a)

        #point and shoot
        if self.point == 1:
            self.yspeed = -10
            self.xspeed = 0
        if self.point == 2:
            self.yspeed = 10
            self.xspeed = 0
        if self.point == 3:
            self.yspeed = 0
            self.xspeed = -10
        if self.point == 4: 
            self.yspeed = 0
            self.xspeed = 10

        #bounce
        if self.rect.right>=WIDTH or self.rect.left<=0:
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        if self.rect.top<=0 or self.rect.bottom>=HEIGHT:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed

        #kill after 5 sec
        if (a-self.b[0])>=5000:
            del self.b[:]
            self.kill()

        #move according to speed
        self.rect.centerx += self.xspeed
        self.rect.centery += self.yspeed
```

my full code here - for you to try

```
import pygame
import random
from os import path

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
light_BLUE = (0,255,255)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30,30))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2)
        self.speed = 0
        self.y_speed = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speed = 0
        self.y_speed = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speed = -3
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speed = 3
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y_speed = -3
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y_speed = 3
        self.rect.x+=self.speed
        self.rect.y+=self.y_speed

class Gun(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,10))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2)
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0
        self.c = 0

    def update(self,player_Cposition):
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.a = player_Cposition[0]
            self.b = player_Cposition[1]-2*self.rect.height
            self.c = 1
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.a = player_Cposition[0]
            self.b = player_Cposition[1]+2*self.rect.height
            self.c = 2
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.a = player_Cposition[0]-2*self.rect.width
            self.b = player_Cposition[1]
            self.c = 3
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.a = player_Cposition[0]+2*self.rect.width
            self.b = player_Cposition[1]
            self.c = 4
        self.rect.center = [self.a,self.b]

    def shoot(self,x,y,c):
        bullet = Bullet(x,y,c)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,centerx,centery,c):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((8,8))
        self.image.fill(light_BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [centerx,centery]
        self.point = c
        self.xspeed = 0
        self.yspeed = 0
        self.b = []

    def update(self):
        a= pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.b.append(a)
        #point and shoot
        if self.point == 1:
            self.yspeed = -10
            self.xspeed = 0
        if self.point == 2:
            self.yspeed = 10
            self.xspeed = 0
        if self.point == 3:
            self.yspeed = 0
            self.xspeed = -10
        if self.point == 4: 
            self.yspeed = 0
            self.xspeed = 10

        #bounce
        if self.rect.right>=WIDTH or self.rect.left<=0:
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        if self.rect.top<=0 or self.rect.bottom>=HEIGHT:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed

        #kill after 5 sec
        if (a-self.b[0])>=5000:
            del self.b[:]
            self.kill()

        #move according to speed
        self.rect.centerx += self.xspeed
        self.rect.centery += self.yspeed

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
gun = Gun()
all_sprites.add(player)
gun_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
gun_sprites.add(gun)

running = True
while running:
    #event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                gun.shoot(gun.a,gun.b,gun.c)
    #update
    all_sprites.update()
    gun_sprites.update(player.rect.center)
    #draw
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    gun_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    #clock
    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What is `self.point`? Let's say, you hit a location where `self.rect.left` is 0, but `self.point` is 4. What happens? You set `self.xspeed = 10`, then set `self.xspeed = -self.xspeed`, so it ends up -10, so you move 10 pixels left. Next time around,  if `self.point` is still 4 you move another 10 pixels left—but, even if it's no longer 4, so you properly reverse to 10, that just moves you back from -10 to 0, which is still <= 0, so you reverse to -10 again, and you bounce back and forth between a left of -10 and a left of 0 forever.

Comment: At any rate, to debug what's actually happening, add code that prints out all the relevant values each time, and it will probably become obvious. Or, if you want us to debug it for you, you'll need to give us a [mcve] that can reproduce the problem. I can see multiple ways you could hit the behavior you describe, but I have absolutely no idea which one is actually happening.

Comment: @abarnert I understood now sorry for misunderstanding before. Best explaination by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing bullet speed in two places in your Bullet update function, one workaround 
could be:

```
# bounce
    if self.rect.right >= WIDTH or self.rect.left <= 0:
        self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        self.point = 0
    if self.rect.top <= 0 or self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT:
        self.yspeed = -self.yspeed
        self.point = 0
```